# How to move wordpress from root directory to sub directory?

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, web, subdirectory

I have tried creating sub directory named "blog" in root. I have placed `index.php` from root to sub directory. I have tried below code:

```
<?php require('./wp-blog-header.php'); ?> 
to 
<?php require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
```

But it didn't work. So give me another solution.

Comment: Have you tried my solution ?? Do you get your answer for this question??

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
<?php require('../wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a multisite wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

copy and paste all contents from main directory to your sub directory. and do the following.

1.Open your wordpress database , select table **wp-options** from there,where you need to change the following rows..
  a). select siteurl row from wp-options and change it from **http://yourdomain.com/** to **http://yourdomain.com/blog/**
  b) select home  row from wp-options and change this also from **http://yourdomain.com/** to **http://yourdomain.com/blog/**

2.After completing this reload your site if it shows any error .Login to your wordpress dashboard and re-create permanent-link (setting-> permanent-link). just select a structure and save to re-create permanent link.

thats all it must works..